# Python asyncio: stop and start a task from another task without lossing state?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I would like to stop a python *asyncio* **task** from another **task** and start it again when some condition in the second task happen.

Please note, than I don't want to cancel the coroutine of the first task (the state of that coroutine when it stopped should be available). Also, I don't care about the exact state the first task is in, I just want the event loop stop running the first task until told otherwise from the second.

I hope this example code helps understanding the problem:

```
import asyncio
async def coroutine1():
    i = 0
    while(True):
        i += 1
        print("coroutine1: " + str(i) )
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def coroutine2(task1):
    i = 0
    while(True):
        i += 1
        if (i > 3) and (i<10):
            pass #TODO: stop task1 here
        else:
            pass #TODO: Maybe check if task1 is running
                 #and start task1 again if it's not?
        print("coroutine2: " + str(i) )
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main_coroutine():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task1 = loop.create_task(coroutine1())
    task2 = loop.create_task(coroutine2(task1))
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
                [task1, task2]
                , return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED,)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main_coroutine())
loop.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to stop a python asyncio task from another task and start it again when some condition in the second task happen.

I assume you control the task creation, but don't want to touch the implementation of the coroutine. In your case, you control `coroutine2` and `main_coroutine`, but not the insides of `coroutine1`.

In that case you can wrap the coroutine in a  an `__await__` that, instead of the normal `yield from` loop, checkes your `stopped` flag and waits for a future that tells it when to resume.

```
class Stoppable:
    def __init__(self, coro):
        self._coro_iter = coro.__await__()
        self._stopped = None

    def __await__(self):
        while True:
            while self._stopped:
                print('awaiting stopped')
                yield from self._stopped.__await__()
            try:
                v = next(self._coro_iter)
            except StopIteration as e:
                return v
            yield v

    def stop(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self._stopped = loop.create_future()

    def start(self):
        if self._stopped is not None:
            self._stopped.set_result(None)
            self._stopped = None
```

You can use the wrapper to modify `coroutine2` to stop and resume the execution of `coroutine1` at will:

```
async def coroutine2(s):
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        if i == 3:
            print('stopping coroutine1')
            s.stop()
        elif i == 10:
            print('restarting coroutine1')
            s.start()
        print("coroutine2: " + str(i) )
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main_coroutine():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    s = Stoppable(coroutine1())
    fut1 = asyncio.ensure_future(s)
    task2 = loop.create_task(coroutine2(s))
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
        [fut1, task2], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
```

The way wrapper works is by unrolling the loop inherent in `yield from`. For example, to just delegate `__await__` to another coroutine, one would write:

```
    def __await__(self):
        yield from self._coro_iter
```

Written like this, you can't implement stopping because the `yield from` contains an implicit loop that yields all the values produced by the underlying iterator - something like:

```
    def __await__(self):
        while True:
            try:
                v = next(self._coro_iter)
            except StopIteration as e:
                return e.value
            yield v
```

Taken like this, it is easy enough to add an `if` that checks for `_stopped` at each iteration pass, meaning each time we're resumed by the event loop. The remaining hurdle is that one cannot just busy-loop until `_stopped` is rescinded - we must yield something else to allow the event loop to resume running other coroutines. Fortunately that is easily achieved by making `_stopped` a future, and yielding from the future. When the future's result is set, we will be automatically resumed and continue executing the wrapped coroutine.

Comment: Okay I understand better why `__aexit__` returning the generator caught your eye so easily in the other question. Anyway, I like the idea of wrapping `__await__` to pause the async function. It keeps true to the core idea of using generators instead of explicit state machines for asynchronous code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it can't be done.

It's possible to cancel an ongoing task with `task1.cancel()` and it's possible to create a new task with `asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(newTask)`.

It's also possible to get the coroutine of a running task with `task1._coro` but if we try to create a **task** again with a previously scheduled **coroutine** we will get a **RuntimeError exception**. This the discussion where they decided it: **https://bugs.python.org/issue25887**

Finally, a possible way of accomplishing the desire effect is using a `asyncio.Queue` object:

```
import asyncio 
async def coroutine1(stop_queue):
    i = 0
    while(True):
        if stop_queue.empty(): #if the queue is empty keep working.
            i += 1
            print("coroutine1: " + str(i) )
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def coroutine2(stop_queue):
    i = 0
    while(True):
        i += 1
        if i == 3:
                await stop_queue.put("whatever..") #put something in the queue
        if i == 11:
                await stop_queue.get() #take something from the queue
        print("coroutine2: " + str(i) )
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main_coroutine():
    stop_queue    = asyncio.Queue()
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
                [coroutine1(stop_queue), coroutine2(stop_queue)]
                , return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED,)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main_coroutine())
loop.close()
```